# $\int e^ {x^2}dx$ : Integration of e to the power of x^2

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, exponential-function

$$\int e^{x^2}dx$$

*How does one integrate the expression above?*

The upper limit of the integral is $3$ and the lower limit $3y$.It is actually a question on double integrals but I am only interested in antiderivative of the expression above as I have never seen it come up in my calculus studies. Thanks in advance.

I realize if it is does not have a simple antiderivative, how would one solve it if it was given as

$$\int^{2}_{0} e^{x^2}dx$$

Comment: It doesn't have a 'simple' antiderivative.

Comment: If you have the integration region there should be a way calculate it .

Comment: @copper.hat By this do you mean its antiderivative is a non elementary function? And can it still be evalauted if it had real numbers as its limits of integration?

Comment: Yes & yes. the integrand is bounded on bounded intervals, hence integrable.

Comment: @duanduan Tahnks for the comment. I added limits of integration, how would it be solved then? And do you know where I can learn more about such integrals.

Comment: $e^{x^2}$ has cannot by integrated by rudimentary means

Comment: In the original question on double integrals, you are probably meant to switch the order of integration (for the reason that $e^{x^2}$ can't be integrated with elementary functions, while for example $x e^{x^2}$ can).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for an exact solution, you're probably out of luck.  If you're looking for a numerical solution, you're going to want to use the equation $e^x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}$.  So, for instance, for the example you gave, $\int_0^2e^{x^2}dx$, you would do

$$\int_0^2 e^{x^2}dx = \int_0^2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{2n}}{n!}dx = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{2^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)n!} = 2 + \frac{8}{3} + \frac{16}{5} + \frac{64}{21} + \frac{64}{27} + \cdots \approx 16.5$$

I got the final answer from Wolfram, but if you really wanted to work it out mathematically, working out eight or more terms, doubling the final would give you an upper bound; in general, for an arbitrary positive limit of integration x, you would have to write out enough terms that for the last $\frac{(n+1)(2n+3)}{(2n+1)} > 2x^2$.  (Since it's an even function, you don't really need to consider negative bounds.)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the integration bounds, assume it is $x\in[a,b]$ then you basically now calculate $\int_a^{b}e^{x^2}dx$.

One simple way is using coordinate transformation,such as cylinder coordinate where  you would have $x=rcos\theta$ ,$y=rsin \theta$.

Now denote $I = \int_a^{b}e^{x^2}dx$, then you would know $I^2=\int_a^{b} \int_a^{b}e^{x^2+y^2}dxdy$, then you consider coordinate transformation and you would get $I$.

It is worth noting that above method only apply the extreme cases, such as $[a,b]=[0,\infty]$, or $[a,b]=[-\infty,\infty]$, the reason for this is that for those extreme cases, the polar angle $\theta$ from coordinate transformation has a integrable region. But for regular cases, there is no integrable region for $\theta$.

Comment: that works only if $a=0, b=\infty$, or $a=-\infty, b=\infty$

Comment: @Momo , it works for any known $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Because of the integration limits, when going to polar coordinates will not have a closed form. Try to completely solve it for $a=0,b=2$ as OP asked, and you will see what I'm saying. BTW, it is polar coordinates, not cylinder coordinate.

Comment: @Momo You are right,the method I use here only works for the whole 2D area. For other regular regions, the $\theta $ from the coordinate transformation can not have an integrable region.

Comment: think about what converting a rectangle to polar coordinates does